# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO, still getting NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint errors

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a custom `UIView` placed inside a superview and sized with a simple `subclassedView.frame = computedFrame`.

It has a `UITableView` subview, which I'm trying to size using constraints-based layouts.

I basically do:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:_tableView];
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints {
  [super updateConstraints];
  [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tableView
          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin
          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
             toItem:self
          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin
         multiplier:1.0
           constant:kDescriptionPadding]];
  [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tableView
         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin
         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:self
         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin
        multiplier:1.0
          constant:1.5 * kDescriptionPadding]];

  [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tableView
         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailingMargin
         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:self
         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailingMargin
        multiplier:1.0
          constant:-kDescriptionPadding]];
  [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tableView
         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin
         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:self
         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin
        multiplier:1.0
          constant:-kDescriptionPadding]];
}
```

Now, the problem is, for the bottom and right constraints, I still get errors about duplicate / conflicting constraints at runtime:

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fd236d12bf0 h=--& v=--& V:[GBTViewAttachmentsCell:0x7fd236d08db0(0)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd236d14250 V:|-(2)-[UITableView:0x7fd233097e00]   (Names: '|':GBTViewAttachmentsCell:0x7fd236d08db0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd231d5f2f0 UITableView:0x7fd233097e00.bottomMargin == GBTViewAttachmentsCell:0x7fd236d08db0.bottomMargin>"
```

Which is strange, because I've definitely set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

Any idea how I could be getting these still? Am I not allowed to host constraint-based layout stuff in legacy views still just setting frames by hand?

**EDIT**: I originally did this with a `UILabel` — these errors occur there because a UILabel has its own notions of "content size". You can either tell it to stop that or don't use a bottom / right constraint. But `UITableView` is being less cooperative here and it's not obvious what intrinsic content size it has.